# Blender white background problem

Tags: rendering, texturing

I'm a new user of the blender, I try to render in the white background but that's not possible, background doesn't plane white like amazon product, and if I increase the contrast of background on cycle engine but that's an effect on product texture, texture go shine and white light
I get this,  [image]
and i'm looking for this [image]

Comment: Can't make head or tail of it.

Comment: You are using filmic instead of sRGB? Maby set background to shadeless, or don't set background, just use plane as shadow-catcher and render with an alpha, if converted to jpg the alpha will be white.

Comment: You should follow the advice of @softyodayoann, but an alternative route could be to disable glossy light rays in the background plane material